# javascript .serialize() function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML CODE**

```
 <form id="createCFrom">
    <table class="ui-widget">
        <tr>
            <td>Event
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="CreateName" name="Event" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="CreateDate" name="Date" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Guest 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="CreateGuestName" name="Guest" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button onclick="addCeremony();" class="right" id="saveCeremony">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**JS Code**

```
function addCeremony() {
        alert($("#createCForm").serialize());
}
```

Comment: please include scripts within script tags!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your id is **createCFrom**

```
<form id="createCFrom">
```

but your script refers to **createCForm**

```
function addCeremony() {
    alert($("#createCForm").serialize());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hi have change `<button>` to `<input>` type and it is working please try this

```
 <input type='button' onclick="addCeremony();" class="right" id="saveCeremony" value='Save'>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/deMba/)

Comment: Why does that help? The problem is the id of the form doesn't match the id used in the JS...

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
alert($("#createCForm").serialize());
```

Should be:

```
alert($("#createCFrom").serialize());
```

(Or perhaps the id of the form is where the typo is - up to you to decide, but obviously what I'm saying is the id of the form has to match the id you use in your JS.)

Correct that problem and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/K5FVg/